# How to trace 'There was an internal error and internet explorer unable to print this document' in IE

Tags: java, jsp

We are getting  'There was an internal error and internet explorer unable to print this document' in IE at client place for a JSP webpage in our application.

Where to verify any logs related to the above error in IE at client's place.
Does this error can be traced using F12 developer tools or any other options to verify the error log.

We are not getting the error for IE in our environment.

Please help us regarding this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried to find error in different browser as chrome?

Comment: this is the server's fault - you need to find the error logs for the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a page is not displayed as expected client side here is what can be done, from the simpler to more complex:

- search the server logs for possible server side errors
- try to look at the source code of the page (normally in the contextual menu obtained with a right click). It is what the browser has received and if no javascript was involved what it is trying to display. You can try to see whether it is what you wanted the server to send
- try to look at the actual page content with the F12 developper tools. This is the current page after possible Javascript code has altered the original data
- use a network analyzer like [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org). This will show you the exact requests sent by the browser and the exact responses received from server
- use the developper tools to trace all actions involved in the page, including the different requests necessary to download the different component of the pages, and all javascript actions.

It may be a rather broad answer but it is the best I can do with the informations given in the question.

And for the *it happens on customer machine but not on my dev machine* part, I have no more than the usual advices:

- try to connect to your server through a raw internet access - for example with a smartphone as router
- ask the client for the exact versions of the browser and host OS
- ask him for possible plugins in the browser
- ask him for possible filtering rules in his proxy - and also control the server proxy rules if any...
- ask him for screen images of the error page, and of the source code of the page